# angular-route-segment: Find current location of routeSegmentProvider

Tags: angularjs, angular-route-segment

I am trying to find current location of `routeSegmentProvider` while I am building my routes because one of them is not getting setup properly. Is there any way I can get my current location in the tree?

Here is basically what I am trying to do...

```
   var routeProvider = routeSegmentProvider;
   $.each(parentNodes, function(index, parentNode) {
       routeProvider.within(parentNode.Segment);
   });

   //here is where I would like to check to see where I am at in the tree before I apply this
   routeProvider.within(node.Segment).segment(subNode.Segment, {
       default: subNode.Default == true,
       template: subNode.Template == undefined ? "" : subNode.Template,
       templateUrl: subNode.TemplateUrl == undefined ? "" : subNode.TemplateUrl,
       controller: node.Controller == undefined ? "" : node.Controller
   });

   routeProvider.root();
```

Comment: @artch Can you help me out please? Your library is working really well btw. I am very close to getting my app working with it.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up getting this to work anyways. Here is my solution:

```
        var currentLocation = null;
        $.each(parentNodes, function(index, parentNode) {
            currentLocation = routeSegmentProvider.within(parentNode.Segment);
        });

        if (currentLocation != null) {
            currentLocation.within(node.Segment).segment(subNode.Segment, {
                default: subNode.Default == true,
                template: subNode.Template == undefined ? "" : subNode.Template,
                templateUrl: subNode.TemplateUrl == undefined ? "" : subNode.TemplateUrl,
                controller: node.Controller == undefined ? "" : node.Controller
            });
        } else {
            routeSegmentProvider.within(node.Segment).segment(subNode.Segment, {
                default: subNode.Default == true,
                template: subNode.Template == undefined ? "" : subNode.Template,
                templateUrl: subNode.TemplateUrl == undefined ? "" : subNode.TemplateUrl,
                controller: node.Controller == undefined ? "" : node.Controller
            });
        }

        routeSegmentProvider.root();
```

Comment: Your solution seems to be correct. `within()` returns a location pointer which can be used to traverse the tree further.

Answer (score 0):

```
<span ng-bind="$routeSegment.name"/>
```

When using routeSegment, above snippet is a simpler way to find the current route.